# Spherical 3-manifold has a finite fundamental group isomorphic the act group

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, fundamental-groups

Picture below is from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold), how to prove the red line ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: This is a standard fact in covering space theory.

Comment: @JohnMa   Thanks, maybe ,I should review it .